# Run-time error 91 that says (Object variable or with block not set) - Unzip function VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, unzip

I'm getting a run-time error 91 that says (Object variable or with block not set) when I'm using the below function to unzip a zip file through Microsoft Outlook:

Function code is:

```
Function UnZipE(PathToUnzipFileTo As Variant, FileNameToUnzip As Variant)

    Dim objOApp As Object
    Dim varFileNameFolder As Variant

    varFileNameFolder = PathToUnzipFileTo

    Set objOApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    objOApp.NameSpace(varFileNameFolder).CopyHere objOApp.NameSpace(FileNameToUnzip).Items, 24

End Function
```

Calling code:

```
Sub UnZipMyFile()

    Call UnZipE("C:\MiZipFolder", "C:\MiZipFolder\File.zip")

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help
Mike

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I've tried your code from Excel, not Outlook as I don't have it.*

When I tried your code initially I got the same error, as I hadn't created the folder or the zip file. However when I created the folder and a test zip file in it, then it all worked as expected. Could it be you've got the folder name or zip filename wrong?